# PHP & Jquery FileAPI - shared PHP server configuration

Tags: php, jquery, cpanel, image-manipulation, fileapi

I'm letting my users crop & upload their image with [jQuery FileAPI](https://github.com/RubaXa/jquery.fileapi). I'm calling this PHP file with jQuery from another page.

Everything works good on my local server, but when uploading it to my production (shared - cPanel) server, it does not create the file.

Do you know if there is something that I need to change on my cPanel or call my hosting company for?

I tried tweeking with header access but nothing works.

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php include 'init.php'; ?>
<?php
if(logged_in() === false) {
 header('Location: login.php');
 exit();
} ?>
<?php
/**
 * FileAPI upload controller (example)
 */


include    'FileAPI.class.php';



if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS' ){
    exit;
}


if( strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST' ){
    $files  = FileAPI::getFiles(); // Retrieve File List
    $images = array();


    // Fetch all image-info from files list
    fetchImages($files, $images);


    // JSONP callback name
    $jsonp  = isset($_REQUEST['callback']) ? trim($_REQUEST['callback']) : null;


    // JSON-data for server response
    $json   = array(
          'images'  => $images
        , 'data'    => array('_REQUEST' => $_REQUEST, '_FILES' => $files)
    );


    // Server response: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    FileAPI::makeResponse(array(
          'status' => FileAPI::OK
        , 'statusText' => 'OK'
        , 'body' => $json
    ), $jsonp);
    exit;
}

function fetchImages($files, &$images, $name = 'file'){
    if( isset($files['tmp_name']) ){
        $filename = $files['tmp_name'];
        list($mime) = explode(';', @mime_content_type($filename));

        if( strpos($mime, 'image') !== false ){
            $size = getimagesize($filename);
            $base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));

            $images[$name] = array(
                  'width'   => $size[0]
                , 'height'  => $size[1]
                , 'mime'    => $mime
                , 'size'    => filesize($filename)
                , 'dataURL' => 'data:'. $mime .';base64,'. $base64
            );

            $iWidth = $iHeight = 330; // desired image result dimensions
            $iJpgQuality = 100;

            // new unique filename
            $sTempFileName = 'userpics/' . md5(time().rand());

             // move uploaded file into cache folder
             move_uploaded_file($filename, $sTempFileName);

              // change file permission to 644
             @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                    if (file_exists($sTempFileName) && filesize($sTempFileName) > 0) {
                        $aSize = getimagesize($sTempFileName); // try to obtain image info
                        if (!$aSize) {
                            @unlink($sTempFileName);
                            return;
                        }

                        // check for image type
                        switch($aSize[2]) {
                            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                                $sExt = '.jpg';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                                $sExt = '.gif';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                                $sExt = '.png';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            default:
                                @unlink($sTempFileName);
                                return;
                        }
                        $data = getimagesize($sTempFileName);
                        $width = $data[0];
                        $height = $data[1];
                        // create a new true color image
                        $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

                        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
                        imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $iWidth, $iHeight, $width, $height);
                        // define a result image filename
                        $sResultFileName = $sTempFileName . $sExt;

                        // output image to file
                        imagejpeg($vDstImg, $sResultFileName, $iJpgQuality);           


                        @unlink($sTempFileName);

                        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                        add_guest_picture($user_id, $sResultFileName);

                       // return $sResultFileName;
                    }  


        }
    }
    else {
        foreach( $files as $name => $file ){
            fetchImages($file, $images, $name);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Also you should remove the error suppression and handle errors appropriately.

Comment: Hi Musa, thanks for answering, I dont get any errors :/ how do I remove the error suppression?

Comment: Remove all the `@` before function calls.

Comment: how big are files...typical host upload limit is 2 meg. SOme let you over ride and can use chunked uploading to get around it also

Comment: Limit is 24mb, so no problem there.

Comment: Ok! found the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type(). the function is deprecated now arghhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok issue resolved!

Apparently mime_content_type was not support by my host. after removing error suppression  recommended by Musa I could catch the error.

I asked for my host to enable my mime php handling and now everything works.

Cheers.